# How I can download heavy something in background?

Tags: android, background

I'm doing an app in Android and I want to know....

How I can download heavy something in background?

Thanks ;)

Comment: What's heavy something? Have you tried using `AsyncTask`? How about libraries like `Retrofit`/`Volley`/`OkHttp`

Comment: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/internet/8865093/Internet-weighs-the-same-as-a-strawberry.html

Comment: Don't get it , why is this question getting down votes? what's Wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way of doing so is using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) , which is a component of the Android SDK that helps you perform a task in the background and show a result in foreground (or main thread). But i'd advice you to read this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) that might prove helpful in understanding better how to handle background tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways here:

1. You can create a Service, I would suggest you to use the [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). The IntentService automatically spans a new thread, through the intent you pass the URL as a String and let the service download using the streams.
2. Use [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) class (GingerBread and newer only)

GingerBread brought a new feature, DownloadManager, which allows you to download files easily and delegate the hard work of handling threads, streams, etc. to the system.

```
 String url = "url";
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setDescription("Some descrition");
    request.setTitle("Some title");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    }
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "name-of-the-file.ext");


    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
```

3. Or just use Volley or Retrofit 2.0 here.